# I'm trying to make a menu in C and my code is not working the way I want it to

Tags: c

I'm working on an assignment for my programming class and the first thing I tackled is of course to make the main menu. But for some reason, the program is not working the way I intend it to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void mainMenu();
void firstChoice();
int main()
{
    int main_menu_choice;
    int _1returnMenu;
    mainMenu();
    scanf("%d", &main_menu_choice);
    while (main_menu_choice != 0){
        switch(main_menu_choice){
        case 1:
        firstChoice();
        scanf("%d", &_1returnMenu);
        while (_1returnMenu != 0){
            switch (_1returnMenu){
            case 1:
            firstChoice();
            scanf("%d", &_1returnMenu);
            break;
            case 0:
            mainMenu();
            scanf("%d", &main_menu_choice);
            break;
            default:
            printf("Invalid option, please try again: \n");
            scanf("%d", &_1returnMenu);
            break;
            }
        }
        break;
        case 0:
        exit(0);
        default:
        printf("Invalid option, please try again: \n");
        scanf("%d", &main_menu_choice);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void firstChoice(){
    printf("Enter the necessary information \n");
    printf("Please enter the student's ID: \n");
    scanf("%d", &student.id);
    printf("Please enter the student's name: \n");
    scanf("%s", student.name);
    printf("Please enter the gender of the student: \n");
    scanf("%s", student.gender);
    printf("Please enter the details of the room: \n");
    scanf("%s", student.roomDetails);
    printf("Please enter the amount due of the student: \n");
    scanf("%d", &student.amountDue);
    printf("Please enter the amount paid by the student: \n");
    scanf("%d", &student.paymentMade);
    printf("Do you want to store another hosteler's information? \n");
    printf("Type 1 if you wish to continue, Type 0 to go back to the main menu: \n");
    return;
}

void mainMenu(){
    printf("Welcome! This program will help you in managing the hostel booking 
    of Wisdom College \n");
    printf("Type the number of your option: \n");
    printf("1. Store details of hosteler \n");
    printf("2. Check room availability \n");
    printf("3. Payment Facility \n");
    printf("4. Search room details of hosteler \n");
    printf("5. To cancel booking of a hosteler \n");
    printf("6. Change room type \n");
    printf("0. Exit the program \n");
    return;
}
```

Okay so when I run the program and I choose the first option which is "1.Store details of hosteler" then just put on some random information and after inputting the required info the program will ask me if I want to continue using it or not. If I press 1 it will ask me to fill up the required information again and if I press 0 it should go back to the main menu.
But the thing is, when I type in 0 it doesn't go back to the main menu, instead it just runs the `firstChoice()` function again instead of running the case 0 in the switch statement. I've been scratching my head for 2 hours trying to figure out what's wrong but I just cant seem to find what's wrong. I'm so sorry if I wasn't able to word my problem properly, and thanks in advance!

Comment: If the variable changes inside the switch statement it doesn't get caught by other cases that would apply, it is only checked and directed to the right place when the `switch(x)` executes.

Comment: Did you try debugging to see how you've set up the control statements wrong?

One point of interest: You will never enter any of the while loops if the related parameter is zero, yet you have a "case 0:" in both loops. How will this code ever be reached?

Comment: If you want to be a software developer you need to learn to make your code work correctly. Yeah, someone here can probably point out what's wrong - but you'll never be a developer if you can't debug something like this. Learn to use whatever symbolic debugger you have available to you, and keep at it until you make it work. Best of luck.

Comment: The `switch (_1returnMenu){` will work only when `_1returnMenu != 0`. Hence, your `case 0:  mainMenu();` is a dead code.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: regarding: `void mainMenu();
void firstChoice();` when writing a prototype for a function that does not take any parameters then place `void` inside the parens otherwise the compiler will produce a function that can take any number of parameters (including none)  I.E.  `void mainMenu( void );
void firstChoice( void );`

Comment: regarding: `printf("Type the number of your option: \n");
    printf("1. Store details of hosteler \n");
    ...
    printf("0. Exit the program \n");`  the function: `printf()` is very expensive in CPU cycles.  Suggest:  `printf("Type the number of your option: \n"
    "1. Store details of hosteler \n"
           ...
            "0. Exit the program \n");`  as C will concatenate all those strings together into a single parameter passed to `printf()`

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d", &main_menu_choice);`  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  I.E.  `if( scanf("%d", &main_menu_choice) != 1) { //handle error }`  Note: the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful input format conversions.  When using the input format specifier '%s' and/or '%[...]'  always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer as those specifiers always append a NUL byte. this avoids any chance of a buffer overflow and resulting undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `printf("Type 1 if you wish to continue, Type 0 to go back to the main menu: \n");`  this statement is nonsense and should be completely removed

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code shows how to write the menu display and handling

```
int done = 0;
while( !done )
{
    mainMenu();
    if( scanf("%d", &main_menu_choice) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for menu choice failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    switch(main_menu_choice)
    {

    case 0:
        done = 1;
        break;

    case 1:
        firstChoice();
        break;

    case 2:
        checkRoomAvalability();
        break;

    case 3:
        paymentFacility();
        break;

    case 4:
        switchRoomDetails();
        break;

    case 5:
        cancelBooking();
        break;

    case 6:
        changeRoomType();
        break;         

    default:
        puts("Invalid option, please try again: \n");
        break;
    }
}


void mainMenu()
{
    puts(  "Welcome!"
           " This program will help you in managing"
           " the hostel booking of Wisdom College \n"
           "Type the number of your option: \n"
           "1. Store details of hosteler \n"
           "2. Check room availability \n"
           "3. Payment Facility \n"
           "4. Search room details of hosteler \n"
           "5. To cancel booking of a hosteler \n"
           "6. Change room type \n"
           "0. Exit the program \n" );
}
```